# Visual Studio: ASP.NET Core Identity scaffolding error

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

Visual Studio: ASP.NET Core Identity scaffolding. Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview - Version 16.8.0 Preview 1.0 ; .NET SDK version 5.0.100-preview.7.20366.6

Error

[image]

> Error: There as an error running the selected code generator: 'Failed
> to retrieve information about
> 'Mcirosoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces' from remote source
> 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.workspaces/index.json'.'

How to fix it?